# Update Magento2 version 2.3.2 to 2.4.4

Tags: php, magento2

When I'm trying to upgrade Magento 2.3.2 to 2.4.4 getting an issue
So I changed composer.json and composer.lock file from Magento-2.4.4
runned command composer update. but while running the setup: upgrade command showing these error

I'm using
elastic search version 7.17.0
Php version 8
MariaDB version 10.4

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar" not found in /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/code/VladimirPopov/WebForms/registration.php:7
```

Stack trace:
#0 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): require_once()
#1 [internal function]: Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration{closure}()
#2 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): array_map()
#3 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(33): Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\main()
#4 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(73): require('...')
#5 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(63): composerRequire0d20ad2e084aeb870108ff1034f78aa5()
#6 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit0d20ad2e084aeb870108ff1034f78aa5::getLoader()
#7 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/autoload.php(30): include('...')
#8 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/bootstrap.php(33): require_once('...')
#9 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/bin/magento(14): require('...')
#10 {main}
thrown in /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/code/VladimirPopov/WebForms/registration.php on line 7

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar" not found in /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/code/VladimirPopov/WebForms/registration.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): require_once()
#1 [internal function]: Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration{closure}()
#2 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): array_map()
#3 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(33): Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\main()
#4 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(73): require('...')
#5 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(63): composerRequire0d20ad2e084aeb870108ff1034f78aa5()
#6 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit0d20ad2e084aeb870108ff1034f78aa5::getLoader()
#7 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/autoload.php(30): include('...')
#8 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/bootstrap.php(33): require_once('...')
#9 /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/bin/magento(14): require('...')
#10 {main}
thrown in /home/oem/projects/PRANISHA-Magento/south/newsite/newsite/app/code/VladimirPopov/WebForms/registration.php on line 7

Magento upgradion to 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

please use the latest version of VladimirPopov_WebForms,
Let me know its works or not.